# ng-repeat doesn't work if used in a template

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use AngularJS with NodeJS to display the users from a table that i have in a database. The problem is the users don't show in my table, altough they can be seen with console.log($scope.users). I used ng-repeat in a template:

```
$<table>
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat = "user in users">
  <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.email}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the code from the controller i used to get the users from the databse:

```
myApp.controller('registerController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.message = 'This is the register screen'
var refresh = function() {
    $http.get('/users')
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log("I got the data I requested")
        $scope.users= response
        console.log($scope.users)
    })
}
refresh()
}])
```

Comment: found the answer. it was $http.get('/users').success not .then

Answer (score 1):

`{{ user.name }}` not `{{ users.name }}`

Comment: my bad, everything is "user.", not "users."

Answer (score 0):

You can do with then function as well.

### success function is now deprecated.

you will get the array in response.data.

response also contain other information as well like headers, status, data etc.